# "Print" value in checkbox from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I´m trying to make the checkbox "check" if at the database is a value.
So, if someone checks the first checkbox I want it to be checked the next time someone tries to edit it.

So I check the first like on the print and it puts on the database the value 0.

[image: Code Example]

If I open the website again I want it to be checked.
I think this is an if, but I don´t know how can I check the box.

```
<tr>
  <th width="15%"> Atividade extra escola </th>
  <td>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-30">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes30" id="checkboxes-30" value="Não">
      Não
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-40">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes40" id="checkboxes-40" value="Sim">
      Sim (qual?)
    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="9" class="input-field4" id="input" name="teste">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Add a `checked="checked"` attribute to tell the browser to check the checkbox. [A useful resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

Comment: The problem here is, I don´t want to do it by default.. I want it to check if is "checked" in the database..

Comment: check if the value in database is checked, and if so check the checkbox  adding a checked="checked" (i like tongue twisters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the variable from the DB and make a condition like a bellow.

let assume that the variable from the database is a boolean `$flag` :

```
<?php echo $flag?'checked':''; ?>
```

In the HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes30" id="checkboxes-30" <?php echo $flag?'checked':''; ?> value="Não"/> Não
```

Comment: If what the OP says here is true, although it makes little sense _So I check the first like on the print and it puts on the database the value 0_ you may need to amend your test :)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for your intervention, isn't 0 is falsy and must do the job?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Thanks for the help, but I only whant the check to be checked if the value is 1 (True) and don´t be checked if the value is 0 (false)..

Comment: But it´s working this way, i´ll ajust my code, really thanks.

Comment: There is only one problem, look here: https://imgur.com/a/SuM3Q2W the value that is supposed to be before, don´t appear..

Comment: It has nothing with the condition, make sure you didn't remove it, it must stay after the input like `<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes30" id="checkboxes-30" <?php echo $flag?'checked':''; ?> value="Não"/> Não`